# PHP get content between commas in javascript array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I would like to know what would be the esiest and fastest way to get contents between commmas with in javascript array by using php. For example, I have a JS array, that I already managed to get from source with file_get_contents():

```
var arr= new Array(
   new Array(
      "apple",
      "ape",
      "average"
   ),
   new Array(
      "bake pie",
      "bread",
      "bottom"
   ),
   new Array(
      "cake",
      "care",
      "call",
      "car"
   ),
);
```

I would like to get all words woithout anny array brackets or qoutes. Also some of the array values contains cirylic symbols and spaces, that I would also like to get. All I know that I need a simple regular expression to match all these words and use it in preg_match function. The problem is, that I am new to regular expression and I don't understand anny of it.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out on this one.

Comment: Take a look at json_decode()  http://ch.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest, try:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```